# How to submit a form with a GET method in rails using ajax in JSON format? (SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, forms

I'm trying to submit a form with a GET action using rails and ajax.

Form and ajax code:

```
.admin_container   

= form_tag path, id: 'patients_search_form', class: 'patient_type_record', enctype: 'application/json', method: 'get', remote: true, format: :json do
        %div
          .horizontal
            = label_tag 'patient type*'
            = select_tag 'patient_type', options_for_select({'Mother'=> 1, 'Child'=> 2}, @params['patient_type']), required: true, prompt: 'select patient type', id: 'patient'
          .horizontal
            = label_tag 'block'
            = select_tag 'block', all_blocks, class: 'float_left select_block', multiple: true
          .horizontal
            = label_tag 'PHC'
            = select_tag 'health_center', selected_health_center(@params['health_center']), class: 'float_left select_hc', multiple: true
          .horizontal
            = label_tag 'Sub Center'
            = select_tag 'sub_center', selected_sub_center(@params['sub_center']), class: 'float_left select_sc', multiple: true
          .horizontal
            = label_tag 'Camp'
            = select_tag 'camp', selected_camps(@params['camp']), class: 'float_left select_camp', multiple: true
          .horizontal
            = label_tag 'patient group*'
            = select_tag 'patient_groups', options_for_select(PatientGroup::GROUP, @params['patient_groups']), prompt: 'select patient Group'
          .horizontal
            = label_tag 'Search'
            = text_field_tag 'search'
          .horizontal
            = submit_tag "Get patient", style: "margin-top: 30px;" 

:javascript   
      $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('Ready!');
        $('#patients_search_form').submit(function(event) {
          var data = $('#patients_search_form').serializeArray();
          var formData = $(this).serialize();
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).attr('path'), // Submits it to the given url of the form
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            encode: true,
            success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
              console.log('Data:', data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
              console.log(err);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
            }
          })
          event.preventDefault();   
})   
});
```

The problem is that I get this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` when I have `datatype: 'json'`. If I change it to `datatype: 'html'` the console.log(data) in the success callback return an html document. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: submit a form with **GET**? why not POST?

Comment: You need return 'json' in action in controller.  Can you paste your action here?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon because these are search parameters to fetch data from the database based on these search parameters, that should be a GET request, no?

Comment: @PiotrGalas why is the action important for this step? all I'm trying to do is console log the data coming from the form as json, and then you use `respond_to` to do something with the form data, am I missing something? Sorry this is the first time I used ajax with rails.

Comment: I'm not sure. You didn't write where you get this error (js or ruby). I suppose that, when you added 'json' then jQuery parse rseponse from rails, but response can't be parsed because you return html from action.